# Activerecord Left Outer Join not working with NOT condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This query works:

```
person.posts.includes(:categories).
references(:categories).where(categories: { id: 20 })
```

But with the NOT condition:

```
person.posts.includes(:categories).
references(:categories).where.not(categories: { id: 20 })
```

The second query completes with no error - but no filtering is done on the results - so it returns all the posts.

The MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `posts`.`id`) FROM `posts` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `category_manifests` ON `category_manifests`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `category_manifests`.`category_id` 
WHERE `posts`.`person_id` = 14 AND (`categories`.`id` != 20)
```

I have not found anything in the Activerecord documentation to suggest this is not possible - am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed with Max. I'd structure this condition like this:

```
.where("NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM category_manifests 
  WHERE post_id = posts.id AND category_id = ?)", 
    excluded_category.id)
```

instead, just because that way you can't get as tangled up in the join table mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that every post appears in that join table *somewhere* where the row in the join table has categories.id <> 20.  Join tables end up looking like this:

```
foos.id foos.name bars.id bars.name
1       qux       5       bux
2       qaz       5       bux
1       qux       6       bax
2       qaz       6       bax
3       qiz       5       bux
```

Let's say youy want the foos that are joined with bar 5.

If you say, for this example table, give me the distinct foos.id where bars.id = 5 you will get these rows:

```
1       qux       5       bux
2       qaz       5       bux
3       qiz       5       bux
```

which gives you foos.ids of 1,2,3.

If you then say "give me the distinct foos.id where bars.id <> 5", you might intuitively think that you'd get the full set of foo ids MINUS the ones you got from the previous query, ie [].  You think you're asking "give me the foos which aren't joined to bar 5".  But what you get are these rows:

```
1       qux       6       bax
2       qaz       6       bax
```

because these are the rows where bars.id <> 5, and the foos.ids from these rows are [1,2].  This seems analogous to your case.

In other words, you want to get "posts not joined to category 20", but what you are actually asking for is "posts joined to a category that doesn't have id 20".  This is subtly different, logically.